# Excel autofill numbers in rows but with text also in the cell

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, ms-office

Im trying to add a bunch of row data into excel, 600 rows in total. Is there a quick way to auto fill the numbers without having to type out each one?

The data in the rows looks like this:

```
check_1
check_1_status
check_1_comment
check_2
check_2_status
check_2_comment
...
etc.
...
check_200
check_200_status
check_200_comment
```

This is 600 lines worth. Is there a way to autofill the numbers so i dont have to type them all in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following formula, if using `Excel` Version `MS365`.

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(
    "Check_" &
        SEQUENCE(200) +
            {0, 0, 0} &
        {
            "",
            "_Status",
            "_Comment"
        }
)
```

---